# What is the name of this screw? (from HP ProLiant quick-deploy rail kits)

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, rack, rackmount

I need the name of the screw for the HP quick deploy rail kit. The screw clicks into the square holes of the rack. It is a Gen4 Rail kit but the screw is like the Gen8 Rail kit ones. I called HP support, but they couldn't really help me. Unfortunately the rack manual does not name this screw either.

After googling a while, I found the compatible "Thumb Style Rack Screws". It would do the job but isn't exactly what I am looking for.

So, what is the name of the pictured screw.

[image: the screw]

Comment: What are you trying to do? Really. Please give us some context.

Comment: I need this screw to click the railkit in the square hole rack. There are a lot of these rail kits but without screws. So I will buy this screw.

Comment: Which server models do you need this for?

Comment: There are diffrent servers but all use the same screw. DL380 G4, DL360 G8 and some models more.

Comment: Okay. You need a bulk package of *guide pins*. How many?

Comment: I need 128 of this screws

Comment: Did you find the screws?

Comment: No I take other screws, the screws from my question: Thumb Style Rack Screws

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The photo you've posted doesn't provide a clear picture of what you're doing or need. You appear to require the four [***guide pins***](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4XUWsrOsKQ) that sit on the inside face of the quick-deploy rail kit. There are *EIGHT* per rail arm (for 2U and bigger servers. *FOUR* per arm on 1U systems). The only reason these would ever be removed is if the rails were installed in a [4-post *threaded* round-hole rack](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apqV7qf0aas).

[image]

You haven't given good context on what you're trying to do, so that's why you haven't had good answers... It leaves us guessing... Why are the pins missing?

Scenarios:

- You broke(?) the existing pins and you need one or more. Call your server vendor and describe the part you're looking for.
- You're missing a lot of the screws because someone removed them. Buy some used rail kits or go back to whoever sold you the equipment.

You can refer to these as "guide pins" and obtain them from HP, an HP vendor, or a used-server parts dealer if you need them.

__

Edit: They're definitely called "Guide Pins". [See the HP video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4XUWsrOsKQ).

Comment: The rail kits are installed in a 4-post threaded round-hole rack and now I want to use this rail kits in a square hole rack. I can't believe that this screw has not a part-number. This kind of screw was built in rail kits since Gen3 i think and cant believe I am the first person in the world who need this screws.

Comment: You're not. But where did the screws go?

Comment: I do not know where the screws are. That is the reason why i need new screws.

Comment: What happened between the time when you didn't need the screws and now, the time where you need the screws? Did your organization change all of the racks in the environment?

Comment: I need the screw now there is no time between i didn't need and now?!

Comment: I guess he bought a bunch of these kits some of which missing those screws. Whatever is the reason for demanding them - who cares? I don't... If you was the person wanting to get/buy some of these, a name would be handy. I remember lots of different types of screws for Rhode&Schwartz equipment. They all had names and part numbers - and the manufacturer will know them.

Comment: The point is that these screws come attached to the rail kits. An explicit and deliberate action is needed to remove them from the rails. They are not available separately. Perhaps some clue as to why they were removed may help in finding a source for them. I've even checked with my parts providers. We can get them in small quantities, but not 128 pieces.

Comment: I suspect the reason will involve the "fog of war". If you can lose a server-lift (sigh), you can lose a screw.

Comment: When you checked your part provider what do you ask them? How many your provider can order? If I can order a small quantity then i get a part number maybe.

Comment: @kockiren My parts suppliers can't order those parts individually. They were only able to cannibalize a few from leftover rail kits.

Comment: @kockiren Did this answer your question?

Comment: This helped me but this is not the answer. I take the  "Thumb Style Rack Screws" now and it works. But it seems to be impossible to get exactly this screw :-(

Answer (score 2):

Such custom screws don't have a standard name. The manufacturer may or may not have it's own name for it (normally not) but only they can tell you. Regardless of whether it has a name or not, what you really need is a part number, as only that can uniquely identify the item. Either way, you need to talk to HP about this.

Comment: But can you tell me a partnumber? The supporter gave me a list with screws from proliant-server but without the screw above. I cant believe it that is impossible to order this screw.

Comment: Return the kit and tell them you want a complete one.

Comment: THX for your helpfull comment

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think it must have a specific name ?

If the manufacturor doesn't give it a name, it officially doesn't have one.

If you refer to it as a `4th Generation HP Quick Deploy Rack Screw`, I doubt many people would misunderstand your meaning.

Comment: Thx for your answer, i need the type of screw to order the screw.

Comment: If you want to order these, the name/order code is mandatory.

Comment: In that case, HP support not being able to answer poses somewhat of a problem, don't you think ? I would persevere with them and explain why you need it.

Comment: I think the supporter was not able to answer my question and i can't find anyone who can answer my question.

Comment: By the way I think the screw has a name because they must make anyone :-)

Comment: ...yeah, you're not improving your case here.

Comment: I think the case dosent matter, because I only need the name of the screw.